# get the height and width

Tags: android-webview

Can I get the hight and width the page web when i enter the Url to the webview for android i need to get the width and hight to this page.

Answer (score 0):

If WebView fits the HTML page in the view to avoid scrolling, then the width and the height of the view applies for the page as well.